# How to append JSON to already existing file with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, variables, append

Let's say I have a data file named "data.json" which contains some JSON or it can be blank. I created a function that packs my JSON string inside a variable, so if I do,

```
var myJSONVar = myJSONString;
console.log(myJSONVar);
```

I will print,

```
[{ "my":"JSON" }]
```

How can I dump the content of myJSONVar to the "data.json" file with Javascript, without the need to use a server side language or external JS library? Is this totally impossible?

Comment: Where is the file? If it's on a server you'll need a server-side script to handle it for you. There's no way that I know of to save the file locally from a browser, unless you have a server-side script download it to you.

Comment: The simplest answer is, "Yes, it's totally impossible."  You really haven't provided enough information, but that's just not the kind of thing you do from pure JavaScript in a web browser.

Comment: If the thing you are worried about is having to submit and refresh the page, you can get around that by using the AJAX pattern: you have a server-side script (for instance PHP) that writes the file, but you can call that server-side script from your page using javascript.

Comment: I am not too sure whether server-side node.js would help in this case.

Comment: OK, what about using an Ajax request?

Comment: @ Mike, Pointy - sure I can use PHP of Python IO functions. But I do not want to bring a third party to the table. Maybe with Ajax requests?

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's very impossible, unless you are talking about legacy machines, in which case you'll need a server echo of some sort.

in current versions of all three major browsers you can download a file with a custom name from a string with JS:

```
<script>
//from: http://danml.com/js/download.js
function download(strData, strFileName, strMimeType) {
    var D = document,
        A = arguments,
        a = D.createElement("a"),
        d = A[0],
        n = A[1],
        t = A[2] || "text/plain";

    //build download link:
    a.href = "data:" + strMimeType + "," + escape(strData);


    if (window.MSBlobBuilder) {
        var bb = new MSBlobBuilder();
        bb.append(strData);
        return navigator.msSaveBlob(bb, strFileName);
    } /* end if(window.MSBlobBuilder) */



    if ('download' in a) {
        a.setAttribute("download", n);
        a.innerHTML = "downloading...";
        D.body.appendChild(a);
        setTimeout(function() {
            var e = D.createEvent("MouseEvents");
            e.initMouseEvent("click", true, false, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
            a.dispatchEvent(e);
            D.body.removeChild(a);
        }, 66);
        return true;
    } /* end if('download' in a) */
    ; //end if a[download]?

    //do iframe dataURL download:
    var f = D.createElement("iframe");
    D.body.appendChild(f);
    f.src = "data:" + (A[2] ? A[2] : "application/octet-stream") + (window.btoa ? ";base64" : "") + "," + (window.btoa ? window.btoa : escape)(strData);
    setTimeout(function() {
        D.body.removeChild(f);
    }, 333);
    return true;
} /* end download() */


   var myJSONVar = [{ "my":"JSON" }];
   download( JSON.stringify(myJSONVar, null, "\t"), "data.json", "text/plain");
</script>
```

Comment: Do I really need to download it though? The file is going to be already created, the only thing I need is the ability to modify its content. What about using Ajax?

Comment: ahh, that's different. though you can easily dump strings to a downloaded file in JS, you can't modify SERVER files without the help of a server, with some increasingly rare exceptions. if only one person needs the appended data, you can use localStorage to memorize it in-browser, but if everyone needs it, you'll have to use a php/asp/whatever script to modify the server's copy or ftp upload the fresh copy yourself. you can at least use the above to code to generate that fresh copy to ftp, worst-case...